# Show a Popovercontroller from within a TableViewCell?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

It doesn't seem to work setting the "inView:" attribute of "presentPopoverFromRect" to the cell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `inView:` is the cell, be sure to set the `FromRect` to `cell.bounds` instead of `cell.frame`.

The cell's frame is relative to its super view and not the cell itself.  Also, the popover is shown *next to* the specified CGRect (not *in*).